# WPF image trigger event

Tags: wpf

Hi I am working on a WPF Grid to represent data.
I have an image called spinner. I would like to show the spinner when I loaded the data (which is already done) and also when I updated the data. Can anyone please tell me how to add triggers such that the spinner will show when the data source updated or changed? I tried SourceUpdated, but it's not a RoutedEvent. New to WPF, apologize if it's too beginner's question.

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.IGrid.IGridControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Spin360" Storyboard.TargetName="Spinner" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(RotateTransform.Angle)">
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:1.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Name="RootGrid">
        <Border>
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <StackPanel Name="SplashPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ZIndex="0">
                <Image Name="Spinner" Source="/My.IGrid;component/Images/spinner.png" Width="32" Height="32" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                    <Image.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Spin360}" />
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Image.Triggers>
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, we add a property like this into our view model or code behind:

```
public bool IsBusy { get: set: } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface here
```

Then whenever *we* call a long running method, we set this to `true`:

```
IsBusy = true;
```

And whenever that long running method has completed, we set this to `false`:

```
IsBusy = false;
```

Now the trick is to bind this `bool` property to the `Visibility` property of your spinner `Image` using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`:

```
<Image Name="Spinner" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource 
    BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ... />
```

Of course, you'll need to add an instance of the `Converter` named `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` into your `Resources` section, but I'm going to assume that you already know how to do this.

---

UPDATE >>>

No, I think my misunderstanding was my bad... I see now that your code is clear, but I must not have looked properly before. If you are using the `UserControl` code behind class, then you should be able to access the `Storyboard` and start it from code when you make the `Image` visible:

```
IsBusy = true;
Storyboard storyboard = (Storyboard)Resources["Spin360"];
storyboard.Begin();
```

However, I think that you'll find that it won't animate properly when loading data into the UI controls because that will also be using the single UI thread. It should be fine when loading data from a database in a background thread though, so you may find that it works for a short while and then freezes.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your answer. However I am sorry that I think I didn't make myself clear enough. I don't just want to show the spinner image. I also want the animation.